# Any way to display an SVG that varies row by row via the standard standard Lightning List View component?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable, svg-icon, svg

I'd like to avoid custom code if possible for a situation where I want to show an SVG in a list view that folds two numbers together: a percent complete and a number of days. That is the second of these columns, where the permutation of percentages and days is so high that the SVG really needs creating on the fly:

[image: example SVG]

The [Custom Data Type](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.data_table_custom_types) mechanism of [lightning-datatable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-datatable) lets me do that if I write my own table LWC because a column type can be mapped to a component that renders the column cells.

But before I resort to such custom code, I would like to confirm that there is no way to e.g. introduce a field in the data model that can surface such an SVG. And that there is no other strategy to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's no way to show anything more than the built-in icons, which are SVGs by default, but nothing as advanced as what you're looking to do. You'll need a custom data table implementation.